# Is it possible to open all files from a session in beyond compare?

Tags: beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I have a beyond compare session with several files in several folders/subfolders, I am able to select all files doing "Expand all" (with [image] tool button) then "Select all files" (with [image] tool button), but then I can't find how to open them all (have a tab open for each file diffs), both pressing `Enter` after having selected all files and performing right click then "Open" opens only one file (or sometime `Enter` seems to got focus on a folder and then collapses/expands it).

Anyone knows if it is possible to open all files from a session at once and, if yes, how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond Compare doesn't provide a method to open all selected files in tabs from the Folder Compare.

Alternate workflow:

1. Open **Tools > Options** (**Beyond Compare > Preferences** on
   macOS).
2. Go to the **Next Difference** section.
3. Uncheck **Limit "Next Difference files" to current folder**.
4. Click OK.
5. In the Folder Compare, **Edit > Expand All**.
6. Double click to open the first pair of files in the Text Compare.
7. Use **Search > Next Difference Files** (Control + M) to cycle through different files.

Comment: Works for me, even in a better way since I does not end up with several tabs open as each "Next Difference Files" closes the previous one ! Thanks !